# jQuery Clone issue finding elements

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp-classic

```
I am using the code below for cloning the form to add new records. My question is i cant get asp to read the new values it only reads the first set not the clone values. I thought of using ajax but im not sure how to code it.  

    $(function () {
     $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
        var num     = $('.clonedInput').length, // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
            newNum  = new Number(num + 1),      // the numeric ID of the new input field being added
            newElem = $('#entry' + num).clone().attr('id', 'entry' + newNum).fadeIn('slow'); // create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value
    // manipulate the name/id values of the input inside the new element
        // H2 - section
        newElem.find('.heading-reference').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_reference').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_reference').html('Contact #' + newNum);

        // Title - select
        newElem.find('.label_ttl').attr('for', 'ID' + newNum + '_title');
        newElem.find('.select_ttl').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_title').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_title').val('');

        // First name - text
        newElem.find('.label_fn').attr('for', 'ID' + newNum + '_first_name');
        newElem.find`enter code here`('.input_fn').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_first_name').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_first_name').val('');

        // Last name - text
        newElem.find('.label_ln').attr('for', 'ID' + newNum + '_last_name');
        newElem.find('.input_ln').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_last_name').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_last_name').val('');

        // Color - checkbox
        newElem.find('.label_checkboxitem').attr('for', 'ID' + newNum + '_checkboxitem');
        newElem.find('.input_checkboxitem').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_checkboxitem').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_checkboxitem').val([]);

        // Skate - radio
        newElem.find('.label_radio').attr('for', 'ID' + newNum + '_radioitem');
        newElem.find('.input_radio').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_radioitem').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_radioitem').val([]);

        // Email - text
        newElem.find('.label_email').attr('for', 'ID' + newNum + '_email_address');
        newElem.find('.input_email').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_email_address').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_email_address').val('');

    // insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field
        $('#entry' + num).after(newElem);
        $('#ID' + newNum + '_title').focus();

    // enable the "remove" button
        $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', false);

    // right now you can only add 5 sections. change '5' below to the max number of times the form can be duplicated
        if (newNum == 5)
        $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', true).prop('value', "You've reached the limit");
    });

    $('#btnDel').click(function () {
    // confirmation
        if (confirm("Are you sure you wish to remove this section? This cannot be undone."))
            {
                var num = $('.clonedInput').length;
                // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
                $('#entry' + num).slideUp('slow', function () {$(this).remove(); 
                // if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
                    if (num -1 === 1)
                $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', true);
                // enable the "add" button
                $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', false).prop('value', "add section");});
            }
        return false;
             // remove the last element

    // enable the "add" button
        $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', false);
    });

    $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', true);
```

ASP CODE SAMPLE to try and grab the clone fields. I realize the names are diffrent in asp but its what i was using. It wasnt able to read the fields during submit
    <%
    if Session("Login") = "" then
                    Response.Redirect "../Login.asp"
    end if

```
Call LogPage("View")

if request.QueryString("Action") = "S" then
                'Read Form fields from posting of page into session variables

                'Continue to read all of the form fields here
                session("ContactCounter")=request.Form("ContactCounter")
                response.write request.Form("SigneeFirst2") & "<br>"
                i = 2
    for x = 1 to Request.Form.count() 
         Response.Write(Request.Form.key(x) & " = ") 
         Response.Write(Request.Form.item(x) & "<br>") 
     next 
 '              do while i <= session("ContactCounter")
                                response.write request.Form("SigneeFirst2_" & session("ContactCounter")) & "<br>"
'                               i = i + 1
'               loop

                session("C_SigneeSalutation")= request.form("C_SigneeSalutation")
                session("C_SigneeFirst")= request.form("C_SigneeFirst")
                session("C_SigneeLast")= request.form("C_SigneeLast")
'response.Redirect("sAdd.asp")

end if
response.write ">>" & request.form("ID2_C_SigneeSalutation")
%>
```

Comment: _"i cant get asp to read the new values"_ - Perhaps you should show the relevant ASP code? (And as an aside, `newNum = num + 1` is fine, you don't need `new Number()` when `num` is already numeric.

Comment: <input type="button" value="Get Data" onclick="getformdata();"

Comment: What is `getformdata()`? I meant you should show the server-side code that is failing to get the values. (I was assuming you submitted all the values with a standard form submit?)

Comment: I attached the asp code.

Comment: Ok i figured out the issue. I needed to move the from tag right below body for asp to find the new clone fields. My new issue is getting the jquery to map the asp clone with the id.